# Would you mind to answer this question?

Tags: spoken-english

If someone asks:

> Would you mind to answer this question?

... and you answer:

> Yes.

...does that mean, you are willing to answer this question?

OR

You do mind NOT willing to answer this question?

I'm confused when people answer to "Would you mind ..." questions saying "Yes", whether they do like or not.

Comment: What is the question asked by Person A? If you understand that, you can answer your question without our help.

Comment: Here, answer No means that the person A can close the window and answering person doesn't mind.

Comment: The statement _"You do mind NOT willing to answer this question"_ is not meaningful in English. If the answer to this question is _"Yes"_, the speaker _does_ mind (he objects or demurs): he does not want to answer. Study the idiomatic use of the verb _to mind_.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the use of the infinitive after the verb *mind* is ungrammatical ([this source](http://usefulenglish.ru/grammar/infinitive-or-gerund) may be helpful).

As for requests starting with the phrase "Do you mind"/"Would you mind", they may be used:

1.When you are asking for the permission to do something yourself – then it is followed either by "if" + "I do something" or (rarer) "my doing something".

2.When you are asking someone to do something – then it is followed by the gerund.

Examples:

> Would you mind/Do you mind **if** I finish off the cake?
>
> Would you mind/Do you mind **my sleeping** here?
>
> Would you mind / Do you mind **opening** the window?

The answer may be "Of course not!" which means "I don't/wouldn't mind if you do it", or "Of course I do (mind)!" which means the reverse.

Also, to agree, you may answer "Go ahead!" or "Please, do!" or to disagree, "Please, don't!" (Then it would be polite to explain the reason for your disagreement) .